# How can i increase memory?

Tags: 14.04, ram

I'm new to ubuntu . I'm on ubuntu 14.04 LTS . I got this error

```
Physical memory usage is too high: physicalBytes = 3G > maxPhysicalBytes = 3G
```

using this command

```
dmidecode -t 16
```

i got

```
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
Location: System Board Or Motherboard
Use: System Memory
Error Correction Type: None
Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
Error Information Handle: 0x0019
Number Of Devices: 4
```

using command `free` got

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8069552    7872888     196664     908496     248808    5355856
-/+ buffers/cache:    2268224    5801328
Swap:      4086780          0    4086780
```

How can i solve it ?

Comment: What were you doing when you got that error message?

Comment: 8G RAM with 4G swap should be enough. There's something wrong with your code. What language is it written in? Just curious.

Comment: I'm not a java programmer, but my guess would be that you've exceeded some 3G memory limit that java imposes on .jar files. You either need to increase that limit, or restructure your code to stay inside of 3G. Maybe a "java" person can chime in.

Comment: thanks for your helping , So you guess that problem with java not with memory itself?

Comment: With java, or more likely with your code. Without running "top" in the `terminal`, I can't say more about your physical memory... other than I don't think you have a problem there.

Comment: Thanks again , but what is this sentence "Number Of Devices: 4" means ?

Comment: Your dmidecode command should have been `sudo dmidecode -t memory`, and the number of devices probably refers to the fact that you have 4 sockets on your motherboard that can except RAM sticks. I assume this is a desktop machine?

Comment: no laptop not desktop machine

Comment: In a laptop, you probably only have 2 sockets for RAM, but it reports 4 due to the motherboard.

Comment: last question in this point ,  how can i know from the details i posted that RAM are used all its size ?

Comment: You probably have 2 slots, each filled with 4G RAM, for 8G total. You machine maxes out at either 16G or 32G (less likely), but to really check that, go to www.crucial.com and enter your make/model # and it'll tell you what you can put into the machine.